# VS2015 Error with WCF References

Tags: wcf, reference, visual-studio-2015

This morning, I am getting this strange error about WCF Referencing.
[image]

```
Reference.svcmap: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'WCFEnrolments'.  Cannot import wsdl:portType  Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter  Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IEnrolments']  Cannot import wsdl:binding  Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.  XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IEnrolments']  XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IEnrolments']  Cannot import wsdl:port  Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.  XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IEnrolments']  XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='Enrolments']/wsdl:port[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IEnrolments']       App_WebReferences/WCFEnrolments/
```

I did the research on the Internet, uncheck 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' in WCF Configurations and it's all fine now and it can compile without any error.

But the problem is that it's affecting all the projects (I have about 15 projects and each project has 5-7 WCF References) I have done.  I couldn't even run/compile 1 project which were all working fine until last night.

Is there anyway to sort out this problem quickly rather than going into each service reference and untick that special check box?  I did install all the updates shown in the Tools - Extension and Updates and the problem still persists.

I am using ...
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Answer (score -1):

Simply untick the "reuse types in referenced assemblies"

[image]